# How to upload multiple files parallelly to amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp

I'm using pure js code and, and I have a multiple-input file which I want to upload it's value to amazon s3, the code of uploading to s3 work correctly but when I upload in on one of the input files and it hasn't finished and uploaded in the other input file the code will be overwritten to the second uploading, so I tried to use the code here https://medium.com/@iamsohail/how-to-upload-multiple-files-parallelly-to-amazon-s3-3b9ac3630806

To upload multiple files in parallel to amazon S3 without conflict, but I faced many problems,

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

var fileChooser = document.getElementsByClassName('s3-input');
if (fileChooser) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fileChooser.length; i++) {

    fileChooser[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        var filechooserr = this;
        var inputFile = $(this);
        console.log(inputFile)
        var s3url = $(this).parent().next();
      var file = this.files[0];
            if (file) {

                // this code to rename input file
            var today = new Date();
            var date = today.getDate()  + '-' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getFullYear();
            var time = today.getHours() + "-" + today.getMinutes() + "-" + today.getSeconds();
            var userId = filechooserr.getAttribute("data-user-id");
            var uniqid = filechooserr.getAttribute("data-uniqid");

            console.log("file name: " + file.name + " file type: " + file.type + "file extention: " + file.name.split('.').pop() );
            if (this.classList.contains('personal-card-img')) {
              var myNewFile = new File([file.name], 'Teachers/personal-card/'+ userId +"-"+ date +"-"+ uniqid + "." + file.name.split('.').pop() , {type: file.type});
            } else if (this.classList.contains('profile-image-s3url')){
              var myNewFile = new File([file.name], 'Teachers/Avatar/'+ userId +"-"+ date +"-"+ uniqid + "." + file.name.split('.').pop() , {type: file.type});
            } else if (this.classList.contains('qualification-s3url')){
                var myNewFile = new File([file.name], 'Teachers/Qualification/'+ userId +"-"+ date +"-"+ uniqid + "." + file.name.split('.').pop() , {type: file.type});

            } else if (this.classList.contains('credit-card-img')){
                var myNewFile = new File([file.name], 'Teachers/Credit-Card/'+ userId +"-"+ date +"-"+ uniqid + "." + file.name.split('.').pop() , {type: file.type});
            } else {
                var myNewFile = new File([file.name], 'Teachers/anythingElse/'+ userId +"-"+ date +"-"+ uniqid + "." + file.name.split('.').pop() , {type: file.type});
            }

                AWS.config.update({
                    accessKeyId: "MYPRIVETKEY",
                    secretAccessKey: "MYACSESSKRY",
                    region: "ap-south-1"
                });

                var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                    httpOptions: {
                        timeout: 1000 * 2000//1sec = 33minutes
                    }
                });
                async function uploadFile(fileName, fileKey) {
                    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
                        var params = {
                            Bucket: "bucket-name",
                            Key: myNewFile.name,
                            ContentType: myNewFile.type,
                            Body: file,
                            ACL: 'public-read'
                    };
                        await s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
                            if (s3Err){
                                reject(s3Err);
                            }
                            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
                             $(s3url).val(data.Location);
                                resolve(data.Location);
                        });
                    });
                }
                var uploadFilePromises = [];
                var screenShot = request.files.screenShots;
                var apk = request.files.apk;
                var cpUpload = upload.fields([{
                        name: screenShot,
                        maxCount:5 
                    },
                    { name: apk, 
                        maxCount:1
                        }
                ]);
                router.post("/updateApp", cpUpload, async function (req, res, next) {
                    console.log("asmaa")
                });
                var apkFileKey = apk;
                uploadFilePromises.push(uploadFile(apk[0], apkFileKey));
                var screenShotFileKey = screenShot;
                uploadFilePromises.push(uploadFile(screenShot[0], screenShotFileKey));
                
                Promise.all(uploadFilePromises).then(async (values) => {
                    console.log(values);
                    }, reason => {
                    console.log(reason);
                });

            } else {
                    console.log("there is no file to upload")
            }
   
        }, false);
     
  }

}
```

The first problem is about the `multer` plugin: I don't know how to use it. I'm new in this, 
when I do `require('multer');` I got an error in the console:
[image]

> Uncaught TypeError: required is not defined

I use `gulp.js` so I solved this problem by  add this code

```
.pipe(rollup({ plugins: [json({compact: true}), babel(), resolve(), commonjs()] }, 'umd'))
```

but I think it didn't solved the problem because I got another problem:

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'memoizedProperty' of undefined
```

***So, does anybody have solution to upload multiple files to amazon parallel?***

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for putting so much effort in your question. You had some typesetting issues which I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using APIs designed for node.js (a serverside js runner) on your browser (a clientside js runner). If that is the case then this is not going to work as long as the apis that you are using are designed for use with node.js or similar serverside plattforms. You need to download node.js and deploy your code in there, and maybe install express.js. There are some tutorials around the web about howto deploy node.js and a app or page.

Comment: actually,  I'm new in using this, could you share links which guide me to the solutions, please!

Comment: sure, you want it work with webserver+browser? or perhaps a console app is enough? for webserver+browser you can check for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs